# How to identify and merge columns in R data frame with adjacent column?

Tags: r

I have reaction time data from an experiment in wide format where every row shows the data from a different participant. Every column gives information about a question (q01, q02 etc.) that was asked, e.g.:

```
   q01_response  q01_RT  q01_complete  q01_button  q02_response  q02_RT ...
1  yes           231     yes           m           yes           459
2  no            242     yes           c           yes           693
```

I would like to merge every question's response column (e.g., q01_response) with that same question's reaction time (e.g., q01_RT), while leaving the remaining columns as they are. The two columns I want to merge are always adjacent. Thus, I'd want the data frame to look like this:

```
   q01_responsexRT  q01_complete  q01_button  q02_responsexRT ...
1  yesx231          yes           m           yesx459
2  nox242           yes           c           yesx693
```

I know how to do that for two specific columns:

```
df_new <- unite(df, "q01_responsexRT", c("q01_response","q01_RT"), sep="x")
```

But I'd like to avoid doing that for every single pair individually. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way using *`tidyverse`* :

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- read.table(h=T, strin=F, text="
q01_response  q01_RT  q01_complete  q01_button  q02_response  q02_RT
1  yes           231     yes           m           yes           459
2  no            242     yes           c           yes           693")

mutate(df1, !!!map2_dfc(
  select(df1, ends_with("_response")), 
  select(df1, ends_with("_RT")),
  paste, sep ="x")) %>%
  select(-ends_with("_RT")) %>%
  rename_at(vars(ends_with("_response")),paste0,"xRT")

#   q01_responsexRT q01_complete q01_button q02_responsexRT
# 1         yesx231          yes          m         yesx459
# 2          nox242          yes          c         yesx693
```

It assumes that you have the same number of `response` and `RT` columns and in the right order (i.e. it doesn't check the column prefixes).

- Our first select calls build 2 subsets of the data frames with the relevant suffixes
- `map2_dfc` iterates on these columns to paste them, keeping the names from the first data frame.
- `!!!` splices the resulting data frame into a list of `q01_response =...` etc
- Then we remove the extra columns and rename the newly updated ones

---

And here's a somewhat more "idiomatic" version, more robust as it looks at both prefixes and suffixes, containing a lot of `gather` / `spread` jiu-jitsu :

```
df1 %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  gather(key,value, -rowid) %>%
  separate(key,c("q","key2"))  %>%
  spread(key2,value) %>%
  unite(responsexRT, response, RT, sep = "x") %>%
  gather(key2,value, -rowid, -q) %>%
  unite(key, q, key2, sep ="x") %>%
  spread(key,value) %>%
  select(-rowid)

#   q01xbutton q01xcomplete q01xresponsexRT q02xbutton q02xcomplete q02xresponsexRT
# 1          m          yes         yesx231       <NA>         <NA>         yesx459
# 2          c          yes          nox242       <NA>         <NA>         yesx693
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also loop over the questions explicitly, if you know how many questions there are to process.

```r
library("tidyverse")
library("glue")

example <- "
q01_response  q01_RT  q01_complete  q01_button  q02_response  q02_RT
yes           231     yes           m           yes           459
no            242     yes           c           yes           693
"

unite_response_time <- function(df, q) {
  in_cols <- c(glue("{q}_response"), glue("{q}_RT"))
  out_col <- glue("{q}_responsexRT")
  df %>% unite(!!out_col, in_cols, sep = "x")
}

df <- read_table(example)

for (q in c("q01", "q02")) {
  df <- unite_response_time(df, q)
}
df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   q01_responsexRT q01_complete q01_button q02_responsexRT
#>   <chr>           <chr>        <chr>      <chr>          
#> 1 yesx231         yes          m          yesx459        
#> 2 nox242          yes          c          yesx693

# or

df <- read_table(example)

for (i in seq(2)) {
  q <- sprintf("q%02d", i)
  df <- unite_response_time(df, q)
}
df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   q01_responsexRT q01_complete q01_button q02_responsexRT
#>   <chr>           <chr>        <chr>      <chr>          
#> 1 yesx231         yes          m          yesx459        
#> 2 nox242          yes          c          yesx693
```

<sup>Created on 2019-03-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>